# Schema "DB" Doesn't exist

Tags: java, derby, netbeans-platform, netbeans-7.4

I use the following code to create db connection

```
public final static String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
public final static String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:projectDB;create=true;user=user1;password=psssword";

public CreateConnectionDOA(String driver, String connectionURL) throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException
    {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    }
```

The project was created in Netbeans-Platform-Application-Module.
When i run the project through netbeans platform 7.4.. it works properly.

But when i try to create a installer using netbeans and run.. the project opens but it also gives an exception

> "ERROR 42Y07: Schema 'projectDB' does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try fully pathing your DB in your url

```
public final static String connectionURL = 
"jdbc:derby:d:/myproject/projectDB;create=true;user=user1;password=psssword";
```

Comment: it works.. Thanks.. do u have any idea how to get the path while installing the s/w which is created using the Netbeans 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Full path works because your relative path was probably wrong. With a correct relative path, it should work.
Keep in mind that current directory is your project directory; write the relative path (../dataBase if necessary works as expected) and it will work.